# How to use multiprocessing pool.starmap with multiple arguments

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing, python-itertools, pool

I have a question.. for using Pool.starmap..

```
p1 = pd.dataframe(example1)
p2 = pd.dataframe(example2)

pairs = itertools.product(p1.iterrows(), p2.iterrows())
pairs_len = len(p1) * len(p2)

tpairs = tqdm(pairs, desc='Make pair data..', total=pairs_len)

def mkpair(p1, p2, ext=False):
    result = {}
    if not ext:
        for idx, xcol in enumerate(p1.columns):
            result[f"D_{idx}"] = float(p1[xcol]) - float(p2[xcol])
    return result

pool = Pool(process=4)
pool.starmap(mkpair, tpairs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I want to get one of P1.iterrows and one of P2.iterrows in tpairs in the pool and put them as p1 and p2 arguments.

but occur "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

and i want I'm also wondering if it's possible to put it in the expression [p1, p2, ext] by adding the ext=True argument.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example so other users can run your code and verify errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code:

1. When you iterate the iterator returned by calling method `pandas.iterrows()` you are passed a *tuple* `t` of length 2 where `t[0]` is the row index and `t[1]` is a `pandas.Series` instance. Your worker function, `mkpair`, will be passed two of these tuples, one from each dataframe. as arguments `p1` and `p2`. But you are calling `p1.columns` where `p1` is a tuple and tuples have no such attribute as `columns`. So this should have raised an altogether different exception (and a `pandas.Series` has no such method either). So I don't see how you are getting the exception you claim from the actual code you posted. Moreover, your statement `pool = Pool(process=4)` is incorrect as the correct keyword argument is *processes* not *process*. So you could not possibly be executing this code (I will overlook the missing import statements, which I assume you actually have).
2. You are creating a progress bar that will be iterated upon *submission* of the tasks to the multiprocessing pool. So even if your work function took a second to complete (and was coded correctly), the progress bar would practically instantaneously shoot up to 100% as the tasks are submitted. So the only progress you are measuring is task submission, not *completion*.

What you need to do, assuming you want the progress bar to progress as tasks are completed, is to use a method such as `imap_unordered` or `apply_async` with a callback, which will allow you to update the bar as tasks complete. If you want to store the results in a list in *task submission order* rather than in completion order and you are using `imap_unordered`, then you need to pass an index to the worker function that it then returns back with the result. The code is simpler if you use `apply_async` but this method does not allow you to submit tasks in "chunks", which becomes an issue if the number of total tasks being submitted is very large (see the *chunksize* argument for method `imap_unordered`). Here is how you would use each method:

**Using imap_unordered**

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools
import pandas as pd

columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']

p1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]], columns=columns)
p2 = pd.DataFrame([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [9, 8, 7], [12, 11, 10]], columns=columns)

pairs = itertools.product(p1.iterrows(), p2.iterrows())
pairs_len = len(p1) * len(p2)

def mkpair(t: tuple) -> int:
    from time import sleep

    sleep(1)
    # unpack tuple:
    idx, rows = t
    # unpack again:
    row1, row2 = rows
    series1 = row1[1]
    series2 = row2[1]
    return idx, sum(series1[column] * series2[column] for column in columns)

pool = Pool(processes=4)
results = [0] * pairs_len
with tqdm(total=pairs_len) as pbar:
    for idx, total in pool.imap_unordered(mkpair, enumerate(pairs)):
        results[idx] = total
        pbar.update()
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(results)
```

**Using apply_async**

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools
import pandas as pd

columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']

p1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]], columns=columns)
p2 = pd.DataFrame([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [9, 8, 7], [12, 11, 10]], columns=columns)

pairs = itertools.product(p1.iterrows(), p2.iterrows())
pairs_len = len(p1) * len(p2)

def mkpair(row1, row2) -> int:
    from time import sleep

    sleep(1)
    series1 = row1[1]
    series2 = row2[1]
    return sum(series1[column] * series2[column] for column in columns)

def my_callback(_):
    pbar.update()

pool = Pool(processes=4)
with tqdm(total=pairs_len) as pbar:
    async_futures = [pool.apply_async(mkpair, args=(row1, row2), callback=my_callback)
                     for row1, row2 in pairs]
    results = [async_future.get() for async_future in async_futures]
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(results)
```

Comment: It's the first time I've asked a Code-related question, so I'm sorry that there were a lot of parts that weren't enough to convey information for answerers.

Thanks for the detailed explanation, and the code you fixed was very helpful. thank you!

Comment: One more question, what is the meaning of the sleep(1) command in mkpair?

Comment: The call to `sleep(1)` was put in just to make the submitted tasks take a longer time to run and therefore make the progress bar advance more slowly so you can see it in action. I meant to remove it before posting the answer but forgot to.